# Fullstack project with Prisma and Next.JS in TypeScript - "Component" and "pageProps" is not a valid prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm currently trying to build my first fullstack application, where i'm using Next.js as my React framework and Prisma as my ORM for database access and migrations.
After i have made the connection to my database, i want to begin with the frontend part, so i have started with the single shared layout component that is shown in the Next.js documentation, but i get the error: "Component" and "pageProps" is not a valid page prop, ts(71005).

This is how my root-component looks like, where the errors occurs (page.tsx):

```
"use client";

import type { NextPage } from "next";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
  pageProps: any;
};

export default function Home({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
}
```

And this is my index.tsx:

```
import type { ReactElement } from "react";
import Layout from "./layout";
import { NextPageWithLayout } from "./page";

const Page: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
  return <p>hello world</p>;
};

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};

export default Page;
```

And this is my layout.tsx and it contains a simple NavDrawer:

```
import { NavDrawer } from "./components/drawer/NavDrawer";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Braetspilsdruk",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <NavDrawer />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And this is how my projectfolder looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from this line:

```js
export default function Home({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
                               ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
```

As the error is mentioning `Component` and `pageProps` are not valid page props i.e., parameters.

You can find the proper props [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) and they are `params` and `searchParams`.